# Change toolbar color, height and views during runtime

Tags: android, material-design, toolbar, navigation-drawer

I have one activity app with navigation view and toolbar. When user choose option from navigation view I want change toolbar height (from standard 56dp to "extend" -> 128dp https://www.google.com/design/spec/layout/structure.html#structure-app-bar) while Iam not chaging activty only replace fragmet. So what is the best solution to do this ? In toolbar class and ActionBar are not method to set layout_height.

Second question: I want change color from white to dark color ? I must instance new toolbar and set it using setSupportActionBar method, beacause i cannot setTheme for toolbar during runtime ? Now i again invoke setSupportActionBar but this good solution ?

Code:

```
@SuppressWarnings("ConstantConditions")
private void initToolbar() {
    mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_default);
    setDefaultToolbar();

    mDrawerToggler = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawer, R.string.navigation_view_open, R.string. navigation_view_close);
    mDrawer.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggler);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    mDrawerToggler.syncState();

    ImageView searchImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_image_view_search);
    searchImageView.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@SuppressWarnings("ConstantConditions")
public void setDefaultToolbar() {
    mToolbar.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
    mToolbar.setTitleTextColor(Color.argb(0, 255, 255, 255));
    mToolbar.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(getString(R.string.app_name));
}

@SuppressWarnings("ConstantConditions")
public void extendToolbar() {
    mToolbar.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.toolbarCollapseBackground));
    mToolbar.setTitleTextColor(Color.argb(0, 0, 0, 0));
    //How extend toolbar from 56dp to 128dp here ? I see that is getHeight() method but setHeight() is not avaible ? Using setLayoutParams to set height 128dp ? How ?
    mToolbar.
    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean "In toolbar class and ActionBar are not method to set layout_height."? Every View in Android has a LayoutParams associated with it through which you can change its height.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it by using:

```
mToolbar.getLayoutParams().height = (int) (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.layout_height_toolbar_extend);
```

and i my dimens.xml:

```
<dimen name="layout_height_toolbar_extend">128dp</dimen>
```

But this is good solution ?